# What would be the "distinct method" that Traversable has in addition to Foldable?

Tags: haskell, containers, fold, traversable

[`Foldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Foldable.html#t:Foldable) is a superclass of [`Traversable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Traversable.html#t:Traversable), similarly to how `Functor` is a superclass of `Applicative` and `Monad`.

Similar to the case of `Monad`, where it is possible to basically implement `fmap` as

```
liftM :: Monad m => (a->b) -> m a -> m b
liftM f q = return . f =<< q
```

we could also emulate `foldMap` as

```
foldLiftT :: (Traversable t, Monoid m) => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
foldLiftT f = fst . traverse (f >>> \x -> (x,x))
           -- or: . sequenceA . fmap (f >>> \x -> (x, x))
```

using the `Monoid m => (,) m` monad. So the combination of superclass and methods bears in both cases a certain redundancy.

In case of monads, it can be argued that a “better” definition of the type class would be (I'll skip applicative / monoidal)

```
class (Functor m) => Monad m where
  return :: a -> m a
  join :: m (m a) -> m a
```

at least that's what's used in category theory. This definition does, without using the `Functor` superclass, *not* permit `liftM`, so it is without this redundancy.

Is a similar transformation possible for the `Traversable` class?

---

To clarify: what I'm after is a re-definition, let's call it,

```
class (Functor t, Foldable t) => Traversable t where
  skim :: ???
```

such that we could make the actual `Traverse` methods top-level functions

```
sequenceA :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => t (f a) -> f (t a)
```

but it would *not* be possible to make generically

```
instance (Traversable t) => Foldable t where
  foldMap = ... skim ...

data T
instance Traversable T where
  skim = ...
```

I'm not asking because I *need* this for something particular; it's a conceptual question so as to better understand the difference between `Foldable` and `Traversable`. Again much like `Monad` vs `Functor`: while `>>=` is much more convenient than `join` for everyday Haskell programming (because you usually need precisely this *combination* of `fmap` and `join`), the latter makes it simpler to grasp what a monad is about.

Comment: The distinct method is `traverse`.  You cannot implement that in terms of `Foldable`.

Comment: Of course not, but you can implement `Foldable` in terms of `traverse`.

Comment: ... which is why `Foldable` is a super-class of `Traversable`.  A super class should be implementable in terms of the sub class.

Comment: I think @leftaroundabout is asking the equivalent of: Could you define a class `TraversableMinusFoldable` , so that ` class (Foldable t, TraversableMinusFoldable t) => Traversable t where` has no new functions but the existing functions are made compatible. As in, could you define `traverse` without referring to anything in `Foldable`.  But even if that's the question, I am not convinced it isn't he right way to study the situation. The old Monad was a mess and should best be forgotten :-)

Comment: @misterbee: that's pretty much it, but not quite. What I'm interested in is just the "weakest possible signature" you could give the methods of `Traversable`, so practical use would actually require the superclass `Foldable`. At the moment, you could basically just omit the superclass like in historic `Monad`, and as you say that's not good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Foldable` is to `Functor` as `Traversable` is to `Monad`, i.e. `Foldable` and `Functor` are superclasses of `Monad` and `Traversable` (modulo all the applicative/monad proposal noise).

Indeed, that's already in the code

```
instance Foldable f => Traversable f where
  ...
```

So, it's not clear what more there is to want. `Foldable` is characterized by `toList :: Foldable f => f a -> [a]` while `Traversable` depends ultimately on not only being able to abstract the content as a list like `toList` does, but also to be able to extract the shape

```
shape :: Functor f => f a -> f ()
shape = fmap (const ())
```

and then recombine them

```
combine :: Traversable f => f () -> [a] -> Maybe (f a)
combine f_ = evalStateT (traverse pop f_) where
  pop :: StateT [a] Maybe a
  pop = do x <- get
           case x of
             [] = empty
             (a:as) = set as >> return a
```

which depends on `traverse`.

For more information on this property see [this blog post by Russell O'Connor](http://r6.ca/blog/20121209T182914Z.html).

Comment: So, if `combine` was the sole method of `Traversable`, would be be able to define `traverse` / `sequenceA` in terms of it?

Comment: I'd perhaps say that Foldable is to Functor as Traversable is to *Applicative*.

Comment: @leftaroundabout try it, and post if you get stuck :-)

Comment: I think it needs to be slightly more general—`combine` is pretty hand-wavey but there's a McBride paper somewhere that goes into more detail about this.

Comment: Ok, so we _can_ implement `sequenceA q = let { structure = fmap (const()) q; values = toList q } in fmap (fromJust . combine structure) $ Prelude.sequence values`. I suppose that's sound enough if we require the axiom that `combine (fmap (const()) q) (toList q)` always "works", with `Just` result. That seems to answer my question, though as you say `combine` doesn't appear exactly elegant.

Comment: Yeah, the property would certainly be that `combine <$> shape <*> toList == id`.

Comment: This is a more complete description of this property: http://r6.ca/blog/20121209T182914Z.html. I'm adding it to the main post as well.

Comment: If we had dependent types we could write `combine :: Traversable f =>  Πx:f (). Vec a (length x) -> f a`.  The fact that we can make the Traversable class without using dependent types is kinda amazing.  It probably has something to do with the fact that it uses the auxiliary class of applicative functors and assumes they follow their laws.

Answer (score 3):

Super hand-wavy because it's late, but the extra power that `Traversable` has over `Foldable` is a way to reconstruct the original structure.  For example, with lists:

```
module MyTraverse where

import Data.Foldable
import Data.Traversable
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Monoid

data ListRec f x = ListRec
  { el :: f (Endo [x])
  }

instance Applicative f => Monoid (ListRec f x) where
    mempty = ListRec (pure mempty)
    mappend (ListRec l) (ListRec r) =
        ListRec (mappend <$> l <*> r)

toM :: Functor f => f b -> ListRec f b
toM this = ListRec $ (Endo . (:)) <$> this

fromM :: Functor f => ListRec f b -> f [b]
fromM (ListRec l) = flip appEndo [] <$> l

myTraverse :: Applicative f => (a-> f b)  -> [a] -> f [b]
myTraverse f xs = fromM $ foldMap (toM . f) xs
```

I think this `myTraverse` behaves the same as `traverse`, using only the classes `Applicative`, `Foldable`, and `Monoid`.  You could re-write it to use `foldr` instead of `foldMap` if you wanted to get rid of `Monoid`.

lists are easy because they're a flat structure.  However, I strongly suspect that you could  use a Zipper to get the proper reconstruction function for any structure (since zippers are generically derivable, they should always exists).

But even with a zipper, you don't have any way of indicating that structure to the monoid/function.  Notionally, it seems `Traversable` adds something like

```
class Traversed t where
  type Path t :: *
  annotate :: t a -> [(Path t, a)]
  fromKeyed :: [(Path t, a)] -> t a
```

this seems to overlap heavily with `Foldable`, but I think that's inevitable when trying to associate the paths with their constituent values.