# What is the name of this functor-ish tag-like typeclass?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, functor

I have noticed that I have a lot of functions that add some sort of tags to my values. As an example, consider these two datatypes:

```
data Named a = Named String a                                                   
data Colored a = White a | Black a
```

and some functions that use them:

```
name :: Foo -> Named Foo
color :: Named Foo -> Colored (Named Foo)
```

At some point I started to have functions with many nested "tags" like that so I wondered if I can generalize this to make it somewhat more manageable. All that would probably nicely work with PureScript's row polymorphism but we are talking about Haskell here. Anyway, here is what I came up with:

```
class Tag f where                                                  
    separate :: f a -> (forall b. b -> f b, a)
```

The law would be something like:

```
fx = let (f, x) = separate fx in f x
```

or a version that does not typecheck but is more elegant:

```
uncurry ($) . separate = id
```

`Tag` could be also made a subclass of `Functor` provided that

```
fmap g fx = let (f, x) = separate fx in f (g x)
```

Instances for example datatypes are as follows:

```
instance Tag Named where
    separate (Named name x) = (Named name, x)

instance Tag Colored where
    separate (White x) = (White, x)
    separate (Black x) = (Black, x)
```

... and some other general instances:

```
instance Tag Identity where
    separate (Identity x) = (Identity, x)

instance (Tag f, Tag g) => Tag (Compose f g) where
    separate (Compose fgx) =
        let (f, gx) = separate fgx in
        let (g, x) = separate gx in
        (Compose . f . g, x)
```

What makes this whole typeclass actually useful is this function:

```
reorder :: (Tag f, Tag g) => f (g a) -> g (f a)
reorder fgx =
    let (f, gx) = separate fgx in
    let (g, x) = separate gx in
    g (f x)
```

It looks like some obvious idiom so it has to be already known by the community. Google is not very helpful when you do not know a name of a thing you are searching for and Hoogle responded with no results.

So here I am, looking for a name and maybe even some libraries to see what else I can do with that thing.

Comment: This looks likely to be related to the `Distributive` and `Representable` classes in some fashion.

Comment: The type of the function and the law you have given it are very strong - a `Tag f` may only contain precisely one value of type `a`. `reorder` really isn't doing anything here - all instances of `Tag` are isomorphic to `(X, a)` for some `X`, so its type is pretty much `(x, (y, a)) -> (y, (x, a))`.

Comment: @user2407038: Now that you have said that it looks obvious. I guess I just tried too hard...

Answer (score 0):

[user2407038's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37039042/what-is-the-name-of-this-functor-ish-tag-like-typeclass#comment61631412_37039042) does get to the heart of it, in that the notion you are ultimately looking to express boils down to functors that are isomorphic to some pair functor -- after all, a pair is a value with something else attached. From this vantage point, there are a few possibly interesting extra things to be noted.

For the sake of convenience, I will assume your `Tag`s are `Functor`s (the relevant condition you mention holds by parametricity), and simplify the types by replacing `forall b. b -> f b` with the isomorphic `f ()`. We might then have:

```
separate :: Tag f => f a -> (f (), a)
```

With the law:

```
slot . separate = id
```

Where the left inverse is:

```
slot :: Functor f => (f (), a) -> f a
slot (sh, a) = fmap (const a) sh
```

By adding the requirement that `slot` should be surjective (which is entirely sensible as far as your use case is concerned), `slot` is upgraded to a full inverse, thus giving us an isomorphism between `f a` and `(f (), a)`.

These functions exist in at least one place in the ecosystem: [the *adjunctions* package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.4/docs/Data-Functor-Adjunction.html#v:splitL):

```
splitL :: Adjunction f u => f a -> (a, f ())
unsplitL :: Functor f => a -> f () -> f a
```

Hask/Hask left adjoints are isomorphic to pair functors, dually to how Hask/Hask right adjoints are [`Representable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.4/docs/Data-Functor-Rep.html#t:Representable), that is, isomorphic to function functors. [dfeuer's suspicion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37039042/what-is-the-name-of-this-functor-ish-tag-like-typeclass#comment61628836_37039042) is, in a way, justified, though *adjunctions* doesn't give us left adjoint counterparts to `Distributive` or `Representable`. Here is a sketch of them, with made up names:

```
class Traversable t => Lone t where
    codistribute :: Functor f => t (f a) -> f (t a)
    surround :: Functor f => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)

class Lone f => Detachable f where
    type Corep f
    cotabulate :: (Corep f, a) -> f a
    coindex :: f a -> (Corep f, a)
```

A few remarks on the `Traversable` connection:

- `codistribute` and `surround` are just `sequenceA` and `traverse`, respectively, except with the `Applicative` constraint relaxed to `Functor` (if there is always exactly one value, `Applicative` is unnecessary).
- By the same token, `cotabulate` and `coindex` (or `slot` and `separate`, or `unsplitL` and `splitL`) can be seen as a manifestation of [the shape-and-contents decomposition of traversable functors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21083521/2751851) (in which we need no list/vector for the contents because, again, there is always exactly one value).
- Various instances for pairs could conceivably be translated through `Detachable`. For `Comonad`, not even that is needed, as `Lone` suffices (see also [`extractL` and `duplicateL`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions-4.4/docs/Data-Functor-Adjunction.html#v:extractL) from *adjunctions*).
- `surround` is a van Laarhoven lens (a `Lens (t a) (t b) a b`, in *lens* parlance), just like `traverse` is a van Laarhoven traversal (`Traversal (t a) (t b) a b`).

Last, but not least, `codistribute` is a generalisation of your `reorder`.