# How is the Foldable instance of (,) useful?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, key-value, typeclass, foldable

I mistakenly applied `length` to a `(pa,ir)` and took a little while to find out, because the code would compile!

So I looked up `:t length`, which told me that its argument is only required to be a `Foldable`.

That's how I found that there's [a `Foldable` instance for `(,)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#line-795):

```hs
instance Foldable ((,) a) where
    foldMap f (_, y) = f y

    foldr f z (_, y) = f y z
    length _  = 1
    null _ = False
```

which incidentally overrides [what would be the automatic definition of `length`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#length).

What is a `Foldable` instance for `(,)` useful for? Especially considering that some of what derives from a minimal definition ([`null`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#null) and [`length`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#length)) of it has been overridden anyway.

---

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426463/what-constitutes-a-fold-for-types-other-than-list).

Comment: [Controversial issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87re_yIQMDw). In my opinion it was a mistake to include this instance, because it can quite easily cause hard-to-find bugs. (In the few cases where it offers the actually desired behaviour, it would be better to use not tuples but [the equivalent `Writer` instance](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.1.1/docs/src/Control.Monad.Trans.Writer.Lazy.html#line-188).)

Comment: Wow. Thanks especially for allowing me to find [this](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat) :D

Comment: @Enlico: there are a few of such probably "misfeatures". I think the `Enum` implementation of `Double` is also not very elegant: it does not generate all possible values between two `Double`s, resulting in some problematic code that makes such assumptions. So better leave these out. The `instance` of `Foldable ((,) a)` like you show it, is (probably) the only one that could be constructed satisfying types and laws, but it was better to leave that out.

Comment: I think it's not so much *useful* as consistent with the instance for `Identity` (viewed as product of one type). There is no instance for `()` (viewed as the product of zero types) in `Data.Foldable`, and there might be a reason for that, but I suspect you could define one analogously : `instance Foldable () where foldMap = coerce; foldr f z () = f () z; length () = 0; null () = True`.

Comment: I guess it's also worth mentioning that `Foldable` is related to catamorphisms, which are defined for functors and `(,) a` is a functor, so it makes sense that you *could* define a catamorphism for algebras with type `(t, a) -> a`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way through which something nontrivial can be done with `Foldable ((,) a)` is bringing in the  `Foldable` instance for [`Compose`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html):

```
ghci> import Data.Functor.Compose
ghci> sum $ Compose [("apple", 1), ("banana", 2), ("orange", 3)]
6
```

Also, `Foldable` happens to be a superclass of `Traversable`, which in turn grants us `sequenceA`:

```
ghci> sequenceA ("strawberry", [4, 5, 6])
[("strawberry",4),("strawberry",5),("strawberry",6)]
```

The perspective these instances suggest is that of `(a, b)` values seen as `b` values annotated with an `a` tag. `sequenceA`, then, shifts the tag to the values in the other functorial structure (in the example above, a list).

Comment: Yeah, though I'm having a hard time imagining a situation where these would be preferrable over the much clearer `sum $ snd<$>[('a',1), ('b',2), ('o',3)]` and `map ("strawberry",) [4,5,6]`.

Comment: `map` isn't applicable without breaking the tuple part first. This particular usage of `sequenceA` is arguably an idiom worth learning.

Comment: @chepner even taking tuple-breaking into account, it's only `uncurry (map . (,))`. Which isn't _super clear_ anymore, but still a lot clearer than `sequenceA`, far more generalisable to slightly different situations, and not much longer. What I particularly dislike about `sequenceA` here is that it suggests very strongly that it's the list what's being traversed, which is not what actually happens.

Comment: I'm talking about memorizing a small set of fixed use-cases for `sequenceA`, rather than having to mentally expand the definition specialized to the argument type. You can quickly explain `sequenceA (x, container)` as "create a new container that pairs `x` with each element of the old container".

Comment: For this particular use-case, maybe "distribute" would be a better name: `distribute :: Applicative f => (a, f b) -> f (a, b)`.

Comment: @chepner It's perhaps unfortunate that "distribute" has been claimed, almost by accident, for the dual class instead: `distribute :: (Distributive g, Functor f) => f (g a) -> g (f a)`. If we had a good method name, it could be granted to [the single-value traversable subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76419522/2751851), which would have `Functor` instead of `Applicative` in the method constraints and isn't really codified in the ecosystem. ([I have occasionally tried "codistribute" as that name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60180893/2751851), but that's not much better than a placeholder.)

Comment: A name, a name, my kingdom for a name!

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR Useful? Debatable. Consistent with other type constructors? Yes.

--

Consider the instance for `Identity`:

```
-- abbreviated to match the instance in your question
instance Foldable Identity where
    foldMap = coerce
    foldr f z (Identity x) = f x z
    length _ = 1
    null _ = False
```

This is consistent with treating `Identity` itself as isomorphic to `(,) ()`:

```
i2t :: Identity a -> ((), a)
i2t (Identity x) = ((), x)

t2i :: ((), a) -> Identity a
t2i ((), x) = Identity x
```

The "usefulness" in each case is treating a tuple as a single value that "tagged" with a value of some other type. For `(,) a`, the tag has type `a`. For `(,) ()` and `Identity`, the tag is either information-free or absent altogether. Folding such a type amounts to ignoring or stripping the tags and working directly with the wrapped value.

Similar instances could be defined for `(,,)` and so on, simply by adjusting the pattern that matches and ignores the tags. For example,

```hs
instance Foldable ((,,) a b) where
    foldMap f (_, _, y) = f y

    foldr f z (_, _, y) = f y z
    length _  = 1
    null _ = False
```

---

It seems you could similarly define an instance for the unit type (which is not included in `Data.Foldable`):

```
instance Foldable () where
    foldMap = coerce
    foldr f z () = f () z
    length () = 0
    null () = True
```

consistent with the interpretation of `()` as the empty tuple. Not only are there no tags, but there is no value *to* tag, either.

<strike>Either this is not a valid instance for reasons I'm overlooking, it was considered too useless even for the people that included `Foldable ((,) a)`.</strike>

Of course, `()` is the actual empty product, not a `*->*`-kinded type constructor that can produce the unit type. As @duplode points out, there is a `Foldable` instance for such  a constructor:

```
-- Adapted from the actual definitions in Data.Functor.Const
newtype Const a b = Const a 

instance Foldable (Const a) where
    foldr f z (Const _) = z
```

where `Const () x` is isomorphic to `()` for any type `x`.

Comment: `()` itself doesn't have the right kind to be `Foldable`; however, we do have `Foldable (Const a)` and `Foldable Proxy` instances.

Comment: :facepalm: That would have been even more glaringly obvious had I actually tried defining it.