# Adequate instantiation of foldMap

Tags: haskell, foldable

```
data MyData a b = MyData a b b
```

Why is the first instantiation good and the second not ?

```
instance Foldable (MyData a) where
    foldMap f (MyData x y z) = f y <> f z
```

```
instance Foldable (MyData a) where 
       foldMap f (MyData x y z) = f z
```

`f` maps both `y` and `z` into a monoid, so `f z` and `f y <> f z` are instances of that monoid. So, why is the second not ok ?

Comment: Both are OK, IMO, but the second one neglects `y :: b`, which is a bit strange. `Foldable` is roughly the class of type constructors that allow conversion into a list. It's up to you to choose what to include in that list. You can even have `foldMap _ _ = mempty`. Or `... = f z <> f z`. These are not natural choices, though.

Comment: A hypothetical justified usecase for skipping an argument would be to store some kind of referential value that does not necessarily participate in the "collection" part

Comment: A non-hypothetical justified use case for skipping (or duplicating) an argument would be a container that stored multiplicities and for which there could be a zero multiplicity, a la [`MultiSet`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/multiset-0.3.4.3/docs/Data-MultiSet.html). I think that particular implementation tries to prune away values with zero multiplicity, but that's mostly a performance optimization.

Answer (score 2):

Your instance is alright as it does not violate any of the [Foldable laws](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#laws), as long as you keep it consequent. It is just odd that `MyData` holds two components of type `b`, one of which is not considered in folds.

Comment: It *seems* like there should be a violation, but yeah, I'm not sure what it would be yet.

Comment: I had a short dilemma with the functor one, but it maps both sides to the same thing so...

Comment: Probably whatever is bothering me involves a side effect, so it's not a "real" problem.

Comment: @chepner Indeed: this is an acceptable `Foldable` instance; it just doesn't give rise to a lawful `Traversable`, as the traversable laws would require each `b` to be used exactly once.

Comment: @duplode Yeah, I think that captures my concern. (I remember reading somewhere about `Traversable` being better than `Foldable` because it had laws or better laws.)

Comment: @chepner As I understand it, `Foldable` was separated from `Traversable` mainly for the sake of giving instances to things like non-`Functor` sets. Still, I don't really think there's anything wrong with `Foldable`. Here is how I'd give a positive spin to the distinction: writing a `Foldable` instance amounts to choosing a path for walking through a structure, and for each choice there will be *at most* one compatible `traverse` that is lawful. [This answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61199603) is an extended look at `Traversable` from this point of view.

Comment: @duplode Here we go: https://twitter.com/GabriellaG439/status/1442869204659539970?s=20. Not so much that Foldable is *bad*, but (my interpretation) knowing that a data structure is `Foldable` isn't enough to know how its instance works, because there's too much flexibility in how it *can* work.

Comment: @chepner While I sympathise with the general point, in this specific case I feel that "this structure has contents that can be extracted in a favoured order" is (barely) enough to justify the abstraction, on a conceptual level. Also, I don't think lawlessness has much to do with the "wat" objections to `Foldable`. In particular, `(,) a` and other such controversial instances are all `Traversable` as well, which is enough to uniquely determine their `Foldable` implementation.